# CSS width 100% OR max-width in pixels

Tags: css, width

How one could create a CSS rule for width which

- Uses 100% width by default
- If 100% width exceeds certain pixel width (let's say 512 px), then the width is clamped down to this pixel width

I am not sure about width and max-width relations, or how calc() is supported or could express this. This would need to work with the latest WebKit browsers and Firefox 4. IE8 etc. support not needed

Answer (score 110, accepted):

That's in fact the intended use of [`max-width`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width). If the computed (actual) `width` of an element exceeds `max-width`, it will be constrained to the max value instead of going beyond it. Percentage versus pixels isn't relevant.

Declare both in the same rule like this (no need for the `calc()` function):

```
#somediv {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 512px;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work if your images are in fact smaller than 512px and you don't want to scale them up to 512px.

Comment: Can I ask another question, is there any difference to set it like `#somediv{width:512px; max-width:100%}`?

Comment: @hugoderhungrige 512px is just an example number used in this question. In the case where you don't want your images to scale past their actual size, you would just set your max-width to the image's real width.

Comment: For that matter, if you want images smaller than 512px to keep their intrinsic width instead of filling their containing block, you're looking at the wrong Q&A. The whole **point** of this Q&A is that images fill their containing block!

Comment: If you want the opposite, say, constrain the size on larger screens but on smaller screens take up no more than 100%, you can say `width:500px; max-width:100%;`

Answer (score 3):

If it's block level element it should be 100% by default so no need to declare the width, then `max-width: 512px;` would curtail it

`calc()` is not supported very well at all, but in this case I wouldn't think you would need it

Answer (score 1):

```
div{ max-width: 512px; }
```

should suffice.

Comment: how would that solve the 100% when the div is smaller than 512?  Would the image not just stay 512 and not reduce with the size of the div?