# Image wont shrink to 200px in div, article not in div either

Tags: html, css

I am making a theme for a friend and I can't seem to get my image to shrink to the right proportions. My article won't fit into the div either. Live demo of site: http://blindersjournal.pancakeapps.com/indexblinders.html
CSS:

```
        .one {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/A2Eps8D.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 65px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: Nexa;
    src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/Nexa%20Bold.otf');
    }
    .navlinks li { 
    font-family: Nexa;
    font-size: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 125px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 63px;
    display: inline;
    }
    nav img {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    }
    * { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    border: none; 
    }
    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
    .two {
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    }
    .twoimg {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    }
    article {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/indexblinders.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Blinders Journal</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one">
    <nav>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zkED7Bc.png" />
    <div class="navlinks">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submissions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Masthead</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="two">        
    <div class="twoimg">
    <img src="http://blindersjournal.org/img/Lisa.JPG" />
    </div>
    <article>
    <h2>VHS umami pop-up trust fund</h2>
    <p>Marfa church-key kitsch bicycle rights, 8-bit mixtape cardigan gentrify Echo     Park. Street art swag brunch, next level roof party Schlitz hella organic keffiyeh      selfies. You probably haven't heard of them polaroid hashtag +1, meggings biodiesel     Portland High Life cray tumblr retro.</p>
    </article>
    </div>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
    var $bgobj = $(this);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));

        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
    });
    });   
    });
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want the image to shrink to fit, you would give it a width of `100%`.

```
.twoimg img { width: 100%; }
```

Alternatively, a `max-width` would work too.

For the difference between `width:100%`/`max-width:100%`, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675637/css-width-100-or-max-width-in-pixels).

---

In terms of the `article` element not fitting, it is because you are giving the element `.two` and its child element, `.twoimg` both a height of `200px`. There is obviously no more space left for the `article`. You would need to remove the fixed height from the parent, `.two`.

If you want the elements to be inline, you could use the following:

```
.two {
    background-color: black;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.twoimg {
    float: left;
}
article {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I need the div 200px tall too. Any workarounds?

Comment: @8bitcodecat Are you saying that you want the `article` element to be inline with the `div`?

Comment: New question, I added a second div and reversed the image so it was on the other side, but it's not touching the top, any help?

Comment: @8bitcodecat You should just open a new question for that

Comment: I can't post until 90 minutes have past, sorry if I seem needy. @Josh Crozier

Answer (score 1):

you need to do some changes:

```
.two {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
.twoimg {
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px width:200px;
}
.twoimg img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
article {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and now everything will fit in place. Basically you have position and display issues, so you need to define the display blocks and then assign your fixed width/height or whatever with img adjusting automatically to the block