# Scaling CSS background image relative to page width

Tags: css, background-image, scaling

I'm trying to make a responsive webpage in which I want to display some button images with a hover-over image. These buttons are 100x100 px, however, I'd like them to scale down to a smaller % of that once the webpage gets below a certain width (i.e. on mobile devices). I currently have the following CSS to display one them:

```
.tumblr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    background:transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/BNYulhj.jpg?1') center top no-repeat;
}

.tumblr:hover {
   background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/BNYulhj.jpg?1');
}
```

I made a jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fszq5v46/). There will be 3 buttons per row, so that at 100x100px each I'd like them to start scaling down in their entirety whenever the available area width is <300~px (a little extra for margin). I've tried defining a `background-size` in several ways but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: I know of `background-size: cover;` I don't know how well supported it is though. Looks like IE 9 [at least](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Examples).

Comment: I tried adding `background-size: cover;` below the url line, but it keeps the 100px image width and then just hides the image underneath each other when the screen gets too narrow, exactly like it did before adding the line actually. Not sure if I'm not using it correctly perhaps? See http://jsfiddle.net/fszq5v46/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

The behaviour you describe can be implemented using a combination of `width` and `max-width` (see also this question: [CSS width 100% OR max-width in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675637/css-width-100-or-max-width-in-pixels)):

```
.connect li {
    width: 32%;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pvcp7Lok/2/

Partial answer because: when you're using an `<a>` with background in stead of an `<img>`, getting the height to correspond to the width is a little bit tricky (see [this article](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html)), so in the fiddle I have just set a fixed `100px` height for the images. In any case, set `background-size` to a percentage to make sure the background scales according with the `<a>`s size.

Comment: To hook on your nice answer, if you want to execute this code below a screen width of 300px, use media queries. @media (max-width: 300px) { ... }. More on media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Great!! This worked beautifully :) And yes, I'm using media-queries to only have this kick in below a certain px width. Thanks!!