# How to specify BOTH max-width % and px

Tags: html, css

**If anyone reads this, please note that there isn't actually a problem here. This question can be closed. If an image has a max-width or max-height greater than its initial size, the initial size will take precedence and the size will be constrained according to its max- properties.**

I have an image that will automatically resize to its maximum possible size with its width-height ratio preserved whilst also being aligned vertically and horizontally within its container.

I want to ensure that its height and width are no greater than 100% of the container it is in.

**However, I also want to guarantee that the image does not resize greater than its actual width so it does not lose quality.**

How can I apply both max-width:100% AND max-width:250px?

Below is my current code.

```
<div class="cell-inner" style="text-align:center;">
    <span style="vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; height:100%; "></span>
    <img style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%; vertical-align:middle;" src="...">
</div>
```

I would like to point out that this question is similar to: [CSS width 100% OR max-width in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675637/css-width-100-or-max-width-in-pixels) however, not the same. I cannot set the width and height values to 100% because that would force the image to potentially lose its ratio.

Comment: I think you do max-width:250px while width:100% That will make it 100% up to 250px.  But you probably shouldn't specify height and width on an image, it might get stretched or pinched.

Comment: @ntgCleaner the problem with that is that I would have to set both the width and height to 100%. However, that would cause the image to potentially, as you suggested, lose its ratio. The container that the image is in is elastic and can be any height or width depending on the browser's width and height. So if the container isn't the same ratio as the image (which it won't be about 99.9% of the time) I'll have a distorted image.

Comment: It seems like just setting max to 100% should be enough.  It will restrict the size but will not force it to grow.  Or am I missing some detail here?

Comment: @JamesMontagne if the container becomes big enough the size of the image's container will become greater than the actual size of the image. The image will be a png and thus if it is resized to greater than its original size it will become blurry.

Comment: @James when you set width to 100% and max-width to the width of the actual image, the image will NOT resize beyond its defined max-width. Either you are not understanding how this works or your question was not on point, create a http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating the issue you are having

Comment: @james But setting a max-width and max-height of an image will never cause an image to grow beyond its initial size.  If the max-width is larger than the initial width the image will remain the initial width.

Comment: @JamesMontagne thanks ... I didn't realise this. This solves my problem - there isn't one. thanks

Comment: @Huangism I didn't realise that the image would never grow beyond its initial size which is where the confusion derives. I tried to produce a fiddle and realised that the image stopped growing after it reached its initial width despite having room to grow in its container. Thanks for the help

Comment: @James then you should delete this question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP told me it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to do anything as your current code should do exactly what you have asked.  Adding the `max-width` and `max-height` to your images will restrict the width and height but will never cause them to increase beyond the images' initial dimensions.  As a result, the image will shrink if needed but never grow, exactly as you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

very easy:

```
img{width:100%; height:auto; max-width:250px;}
```

here you're saying: "let's make this image as wide as possible preserving its proportional height, however, let's not grow over 250px width". Since height is still auto, the height proportion will still be kept as intended

**EDIT**

Since question isn't clear, different scenarios

```
img{height:100%; width: auto;}
```

in this case, image will be as high as possible, and obviously as wide as possible. Works great when we have a lot of portrait images with unknown size.

```
img{max-width: 100%; height:auto; max-height:200px !important;  }
```

in this case, image will adjust to 100% width with proportional height. However, if height reaches 200px, then the width will adjust proportionally

Comment: I probably shouldn't have placed so much emphasis on the width because there will be instances where the height will fill the container and the width will not be 100%. This solution only works if the available space in the container is great enough for the width to fill the width of its container. However, if the container is short and fat, then the image will not fit the entire width and ought to resize to 100% height and have the width resize accordingly.

Comment: your question isn't very clear because I can't understand how an image will grow beyond its boundaries, but if it's what I think, then try the opposite: `height:100%; width: auto;`

Comment: Thanks for your help...This is what I had meant: http://jsfiddle.net/4RPFa/5724/ I suspected that the image would grow beyond its initial actual size and grow to fit the container but it doesn't.

Comment: well, your original question is the total opposite to what you later edited as what the real question was, that's why me and everybody else was so confused

Comment: I didn't change the question I just added the bit to the top

Answer (score 0):

Though more complicated, you can also do this with Javascript. It allows you to resize images dynamically, say when the browser window changes size. This example uses a max height of 400 px and max width of 250 px. Right now it's static, but you could easily make it take into consideration dynamic changes like window size. Keep in mind that unless you plan to do something dynamically, James Montagne's answer is the correct one.

```
    var imageID = //ID of image in question goes here
    var newWidth;
    var newHeight;
    var maxHeight = 400;
    var maxWidth = 250;
    var imgDOM = $('#' + imageID);
    var imgHeight = imgDOM[0].naturalHeight;
    var imgWidth = imgDOM[0].naturalWidth;
    if(imgHeight <= 400) {
        if(imgWidth <= 250) {
            newWidth = imgWidth;
            newHeight = imgHeight;
        }
        else {
            newWidth = 250;
            newHeight = imgHeight * newWidth / imgWidth;
        }
    }
    else {
        newHeight = 400;
        newWidth = imgWidth * newHeight / imgHeight;
        if(newWidth <= 250) {
            //do nothing
        }
        else {
            newWidth = 250;
            newHeight = imgHeight * newWidth / imgWidth;
        }
    }
    imgDOM.attr("width", newWidth);
```