# How do I middle align a container parent?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid, container-queries

I have a `main` grid. Its grid items are also containers (`container-type: inline-size`), which helps with giving them various internal layouts depending on their width.

**How can I middle align `main` once it passes a certain width?** Both `justify-self: center` and `margin: 0 auto` on `main` make the whole thing break - you can see this by uncommenting those two lines in the snippet below. Same happens with `justify-content: center` (on `main` or on the `body`).

Expand the snippet below and resize the viewport to see what happens above the `max-width` set for `main`: it stays on the left. I want it middle aligned horizontally, but everything I've tried makes it collapse.

```js
addEventListener('input', e => {
    document.body.style = `--${e.target.id}: 1`
})
```

```css
/* basic reset, grid everything */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
html, body, main, section, div, ul, figure { display: grid }
html { min-height: 100% }

body {
    /* body stle may override these two; 
     * they're mutually exclusive */
    /* 1 if images are _N_ext to each other, 0 otherwise */
    --_n: var(--n, 0);
    /* 1 if images are _S_tacked, 0 otherwise */
    --_s: var(--s, 0);
    
    font: clamp(.75em, 3.375vw, 1.25em)/ 1.25 sans-serif;
}

main {
    grid-gap: .5em;
    align-self: center;
    /* need this, but it collapses layout *
    justify-self: center;
  /* same happens with this *
    margin: 0 auto; /*  */
    padding: .5em;
    max-width: 800px
}

/* CSS variable indices for similar items */
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(1) { --i: 0 }
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(2) { --i: 1 }
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(3) { --i: 2 }
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(4) { --i: 3 }

.ctr {
    grid-gap: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    background: gainsboro;
}

div { grid-gap: inherit }

.one, .two, .res {
    container-type: inline-size;
    
    * {
        /* a bunch of container size cases */
        --_cs0: var(--cs0, 1);
        --_cs1: var(--cs1, calc(1 - var(--_cs0)));
        --_cs2: var(--cs2, calc(1 - (var(--_cs0) + var(--_cs1))));
    }
}

/* SECTION 1 */
.boo, .foo {
    @container (min-width: 23em) { --cs0: 0 }
    @container (min-width: 32em) { --cs1: 0 }
}

.boo {
    grid-column: calc(2 - var(--_cs1))/ span calc(1 + var(--_cs1))
}

li {
    grid-column: calc(1 + var(--_cs1)*var(--i))
}

.foo {
    grid-area: calc(1 + var(--_cs1))/ 1;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content)
}

.xtra {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc((1 - var(--_cs0))*9em)
}


/* SECTION 2 */
[name='c'], [for] {
    grid-area: 
        calc(1 + var(--i)*var(--_cs0))/ 
        calc(1 + var(--i)*var(--_cs1));
    
    @container (min-width: 20em) { --cs0: 0 }
}



/* SECTION 4 */
figure {
    grid-area: calc(1 + var(--_cs0)*var(--i)*var(--_n))/ 
        calc(1 + var(--_cs1)*var(--i)*var(--_n));
    max-width: 400px;
    aspect-ratio: 2/ calc(2 + var(--_s) + var(--_cs1)*var(--_n));
    
    @container (min-width: 20em) { --cs0: 0  }
}

img {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: var(--pos)
}
```

```html
<body style="--n: 1">
  <main>
    <section class="ctr one">
      <ul class="boo">
        <li>listitem</li>
        <li>listitem</li>
        <li>listitem</li>
        <li>listitem</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="xtra">superfluous</div>
        <div class="main">
          <div>some</div>
          <div>essential</div>
          <div>shit</div>
          <div>keep it!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="ctr two">
      <input id="n" type="radio" name="c" checked="checked"/>
      <label for="n">side by side</label>
      <input id="s" type="radio" name="c"/>
      <label for="s">stacked</label>
    </section>
    <section class="ctr tre">
      <div>more stuff</div>
    </section>
    <section class="res">
      <figure><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705630547844-29adf8323f28?w=800"/></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705630547844-29adf8323f28?w=800"/></figure>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Parent or child container, just want to clarify this with you

Comment: @Richie I don't understand the question? I want to middle align `main` horizontally. `main` is the parent of the container elements (which have `container-type: inline-size`) set on them.

Comment: I guess you already thought about giving `main` a `width`. And setting it to `margin:0 auto`?

Comment: @deEr. It's all in my question above. `main` has a `max-width`. It needs to be flexible up to that point. `margin: 0 auto` makes the layout collapse because the children of the `main` have `container-type: inline-size` (needed for their internal layout) set on them. Hmm, you've given me another idea with CSS functions.

Comment: There was a trick, when to use `max-width`, but i forgot. However `max-width` is to use, when you use `vw`for example.  You explicitly have to set a `width`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675671/2569323

Comment: when you make the element a container, always consider you have no content inside it (empty) because the content will no more define the width of the container. That's why you need to explicitly define a width otherwise the centering will make your element shrink-to-fit and since it's considered empty, everything will collapse.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<img>` and all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: i don't know how much are you inclined in having a media-query there. But something like this can work. 
`@media (min-width: 800px) {
    main {
        margin-inline: calc((100cqw - 800px) / 2);
    }
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@deEr. leaving a comment about giving `main` a `width` gave me an idea. `main` needs to be flexible up to a certain point, so it gets a `max-width` to prevent it from growing above that point.

Buuut... it could also get a `width: min(100%, 800px)` instead of that `max-width`. With an added `box-sizing: border-box` to prevent overflow since it has a `padding`.

Then all the methods I've tried before and didn't work suddenly work!

Answer (score 1):

`width: 100%` should do the job as well

```js
addEventListener('input', e => {
    document.body.style = `--${e.target.id}: 1`
})
```

```css
/* basic reset, grid everything */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
html,body, main, section, div, ul, figure { display: grid }
html { min-height: 100% }

body {
    /* body stle may override these two; 
     * they're mutually exclusive */
    /* 1 if images are _N_ext to each other, 0 otherwise */
    --_n: var(--n, 0);
    /* 1 if images are _S_tacked, 0 otherwise */
    --_s: var(--s, 0);
    
    font: clamp(.75em, 3.375vw, 1.25em)/ 1.25 sans-serif;
}

main {
    grid-gap: .5em;
    place-self: center;
    padding: .5em;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* CSS variable indices for similar items */
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(1) { --i: 0 }
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(2) { --i: 1 }
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(3) { --i: 2 }
:is(input, label, li, figure):nth-of-type(4) { --i: 3 }

.ctr {
    grid-gap: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    background: gainsboro;
}

div { grid-gap: inherit }

.one, .two, .res {
    container-type: inline-size;
    
    * {
        /* a bunch of container size cases */
        --_cs0: var(--cs0, 1);
        --_cs1: var(--cs1, calc(1 - var(--_cs0)));
        --_cs2: var(--cs2, calc(1 - (var(--_cs0) + var(--_cs1))));
    }
}

/* SECTION 1 */
.boo, .foo {
    @container (min-width: 23em) { --cs0: 0 }
    @container (min-width: 32em) { --cs1: 0 }
}

.boo {
    grid-column: calc(2 - var(--_cs1))/ span calc(1 + var(--_cs1))
}

li {
    grid-column: calc(1 + var(--_cs1)*var(--i))
}

.foo {
    grid-area: calc(1 + var(--_cs1))/ 1;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content)
}

.xtra {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc((1 - var(--_cs0))*9em)
}


/* SECTION 2 */
[name='c'], [for] {
    grid-area: 
        calc(1 + var(--i)*var(--_cs0))/ 
        calc(1 + var(--i)*var(--_cs1));
    
    @container (min-width: 20em) { --cs0: 0 }
}



/* SECTION 4 */
figure {
    grid-area: calc(1 + var(--_cs0)*var(--i)*var(--_n))/ 
        calc(1 + var(--_cs1)*var(--i)*var(--_n));
    max-width: 400px;
    aspect-ratio: 2/ calc(2 + var(--_s) + var(--_cs1)*var(--_n));
    
    @container (min-width: 20em) { --cs0: 0  }
}

img {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: var(--pos)
}
```

```html
<body style="--n: 1">
  <main>
    <section class="ctr one">
      <ul class="boo">
        <li>listitem</li>
        <li>listitem</li>
        <li>listitem</li>
        <li>listitem</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="xtra">superfluous</div>
        <div class="main">
          <div>some</div>
          <div>essential</div>
          <div>shit</div>
          <div>keep it!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="ctr two">
      <input id="n" type="radio" name="c" checked="checked"/>
      <label for="n">side by side</label>
      <input id="s" type="radio" name="c"/>
      <label for="s">stacked</label>
    </section>
    <section class="ctr tre">
      <div>more stuff</div>
    </section>
    <section class="res">
      <figure><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705630547844-29adf8323f28?w=800"/></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705630547844-29adf8323f28?w=800"/></figure>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

you should not use max-width property of css use only width property for center main tag and use vw(view-port) unit width for responsiveness then apply justify self property on css

correction of your css :

```
main {
    grid-gap: .5em;
   
    padding: .5em;
    justify-self: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 80vw;

}
```

that help you for do center main section

Comment: `width: 80vw` is not what I want in any scenario.

Comment: write           div with class container  and add you main section in this div and write css like      .container{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: That isn't what I want either.